# How to use parameters from response in new request in Nuclei?

Tags: web-application, vulnerability-scanners

I need to use [Nuclei](https://github.com/projectdiscovery/nuclei) to create some templates for a site. But to locate the bug, I have to use some information that the site returns after the first request. Is it possible to take it from the response and use it in the next request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is. You have to create a workspace and choose templates who use parameter as a subtemplate and the one where you take it (use extractors for that) as template like that:

```
    workflows:
      - template: get-parameter.yaml
        subtemplates:
          - template: using-parameter.yaml
          - template: using-parameter2.yaml
          - template: using-parameter3.yaml
```

That link can be useful for research: [link](https://nuclei.projectdiscovery.io/templating-guide/workflows/#shared-execution-context)